# Thread join failed invalid argument

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote this function to solve a sudoku game implementing a backtrack algorithm, and I want to parallelize it using the threads library. I am getting an error

```
thread::join failed: Invalid argument
```

when I join the threads in the following method can some tell me how can I fix it.

```cpp
bool solveSudoku9x9(int sudoku[9][9], int row, int col)
{
    if (row > 8) return true;
    if (sudoku[row][col] != 0) {
        int rowNext, colNext;
        nextEmpty(sudoku, row, col, rowNext, colNext);
        return solveSudoku9x9(sudoku, rowNext, colNext);
    }

    std::vector<int> placebles = findPlaceables(sudoku, row, col);

    if (placebles.size() == 0) {
        
        return false;
    
    };

    bool status = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < placebles.size(); i++) {
        int n = placebles[i];
        int sudokuCopy[9][9];
        copyArray(sudoku, sudokuCopy);
        //cout << "(" << row << "," << col << ") =>" << n << endl;
        sudokuCopy[row][col] = n;
        int rowNext = row;
        int colNext = col;
        if(k<4){
            threadVect.emplace_back(solveSudoku9x9,sudoku, rowNext, colNext);
            for(auto& t : threadVect){
                if(t.joinable()){t.join();}
            }
            k++;
        }
        nextEmpty(sudokuCopy, row, col, rowNext, colNext);
        if (solveSudoku9x9(sudokuCopy, rowNext, colNext)) {
            copyArray(sudokuCopy, sudoku);
            status = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Where / how did you define `threadVect` ? given that you call `solveSudoku9x9` from multiple threads you might have a race-condition on `threadVect`. - additionally you can only call `.join()` once on every thread object, after that it's dead (i.e. calling `.join()` again on it will result in an error), so you need to remove it again from `threadVect` once you joined it.

Comment: @Turtlefight threadVect is a global variable in the code

Comment: @edak -- Multithreaded programming is much more than knowing how to create threads.  Your implementation lacks any synchronization or code to protect two or more threads accessing your global data.

Comment: global variables are problematic (everything can affect the global, so everything has the potential for unannounced side effects) and often an unnecessary shot to the foot when writing a multithreaded program (everything can now affect the global all at the same time). Tread cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `solveSudoku9x9` itself in a new thread and both executions of this function, hence both threads, access `threadVect` (which I assume is not declared as thread local) and probably more variables for read and write operations. That is called a *data race*.

You cannot access non-atomic objects for read and write operations from multiple threads without synchronization. Data races cause the program to have *undefined behavior*, which seems to manifest for you in the way you observe.

All variables that are not only *read* by multiple threads need to be guarded by a mutex (or by atomics).

---

Also, given that you call `join` immediately after creating a new thread, your threads are effectively (with exception of the access to `threadVect`) running synchronously. They are not providing any benefit. I assume that your intend was to join the threads later after one of the loops. (I have not checked the logic of your code.)

---

I suspect that you have more problems of similar kind if you actually let multiple of the threads run in parallel (see above), but I am focusing on the one closest related to your stated problem. Specifically `sudoku` does not look safe to me, since you are passing it by pointer

---

Instead of recursively starting threads, start all threads that you need in the main thread, so that the other threads don't need to access `threadVect`. It doesn't make sense to use significantly more threads than you have logical cores on your CPU anyway.

I would recommend that you simply give each thread a copy of the problem and subdivide the solution space that needs to be tested between them, so that they never have to access shared memory.